# Change encryted home files to not hidden directory

Tags: linux, ecryptfs

I'm using Linux Mint 19 Tara with home folder encryption set during OS installation.
I know that my encrypted files are stored under `~/home/.ecryptfs`
But I need to have them under not hidden directory, for example  `~/home/ecryptfs`.

How can I change the encrypted home files directory to achieve that?
I want to have everything working as it is now (with home and swap encrypted) but in different (not hidden) location.

Comment: just symlink it?

Comment: I tried it already (like this: `sudo ln -s .ecryptfs encrypted`), but it doesn't solve my case (software which looks for this directory still doesn't see it).

Comment: What software would that be, not clear which problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: It's Synology Cloud Station Drive, it's not able to point to hidden directory. I'm sure there is way to change ecryptfs directory, but I don't know how to do it without risk to break encryption mounting/unmounting etc.

Comment: If your synology software doesn't sync any "hidden" dot-files, then what use is it? Even if you could make it read your home, it's full of dot-files & folders like `.config`, `.bash*`, `.profile`, etc anyway? Sounds like a deal-breaker - but the windows client appears to have an option 'Sync files & folders that begin with "."' so maybe you can just change that, if it exists for linux

Comment: It does sync hidden files with option you've mentioned, but it cannot point to hidden directory (it's simple not visible on selection tree). So if it was not hidden then everything will work (including sync of hidden files).

Comment: If the option is also called 'Sync files **& folders** that begin with "."' but it doesn't really sync folders that begin with a dot, that sounds like a bug, and you still don't get your `.config` folder, again breaking the deal of "working backup software"

Comment: It does sync hidden folders with that option. For example if you point your syncing to _/home/xyzuser_ and select that option, then everything from _xyzuser_ directory is synced, including hidden files and directories. Please stop focusing at Synology Software, it works fine but it cannot point to hidden directory and such change is not in theirs road map and I can't do anything about it (I already talked to them). Instead please focus at the topic question - how to change encryption directory. Thank you for engagement, I appreciate it, but focusing at Synology Soft doesn't help :)